# New SKScene Set as Default in SpriteKit Game Turns Out Blank

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I have 2 SKScene.

1. GameScene
2. WelcomeScene.swift

I wanted my screen to load up "WelcomeScene" first instead of the default GameScene.Thus, I've edited "GameViewController.swift" accordingly. However, all I get is a blank screen, and couldn't locate what went wrong.

Here's my code in "GameViewController".

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "WelcomeScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

Comment: in the edited comments you say that my answer helped you to figure it out, you should then mark my answer as helpful and or correct so that others can benefit from this question. It is not proper to try to edit my answer to results that tailor to your circumstances.

Comment: Is it alright to mark your answer as correct if the code is not fully workable? Because I did edit from yours to make it work.

Comment: the code is workable! just because it didn't 100% match your exact scenario doesn't make it incorrect. Almost all answers on SO need to be slightly adjusted to fit the end user and the end user's scenario. By narrowing down the answer to only fit your code you are limiting the possibilities of helping others with SIMILAR issues

Comment: My apologies if I’ve offended you in any way. I’m new to stack overflow, still unsure about the culture here. Will mark your comment as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a corresponding SKS file created in the Scene editor then you load your scene like so...

```
// Load the SKScene from WelcomeScene.sks'
if let welcomeScene = WelcomeScene(fileNamed: "WelcomeScene")  {
    welcomeScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    view.presentScene(welcomeScene)
}
```

if you do not have a corresponding SKS file created in the scene editor but would rather load the scene that was created in code use...

```
welcomeScene= WelcomeScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
welcomeScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
skView.presentScene(welcomeScene)
```